# Lessphp: Failed to assign arg @list

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, less

I use [php less compiler](http://leafo.net/lessphp/) to compile **bootstrap.less**. When I upload on the server bootstrap.less via smartFTP everything works fine.

But as soon as I open and save **bootstrap.less** on the server (without changing it, just save it using remote editor linke PSPad or Remote System Explorer in Eclipse) I got the error:

```
 Failed to assign arg @list: ../_css/less/bootstrap.less on line 51
```

So saving the file does something strange, but why and what?

Comment: Keep an eye on the corresponding bug reports at the lessphp project: https://github.com/leafo/lessphp/issues/432 & https://github.com/leafo/lessphp/issues/491 – Apparently they are aware of the issue and working on it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @max-k it's a bug. All above version 3.0.0 don't work.

Lessphp seems to break on mixins like   `.col(@index) when (@index = 1) { // initial`.

Solutions: switch back to TB3.0.0, wait for the bug fix, use a alternative library like [less.php](https://github.com/oyejorge/less.php)